# How to access previous string while reading from a file?

Tags: c++, c++14, ifstream

I need some help with a project I'm working on. In the program I'm reading in strings from a file and doing different things depending on if they have punctuation marks or not. If the string has punctuation you separate the punctuation and set it as a value to the string key, then set the end of sentence value as "$", then lastly set the key for the beginning of the next sentence as "^" with the next read in string as its value.  I have the code for where it ends with a punctuation finished, but i'm not sure entirely what to do if it DOESN'T have punctuation.

Essentially if the read in string doesn't have punctuation marks then i want to simply do: `mapName[previousString].push_back(newString)`

But how do i access that previous string? If i try to read in 2 strings at once i would still have to check for punctuation, which defeats the purpose of checking only once for punctuation. Apologies if this is a dumb question, but i've been trying to work on this all day yesterday and today. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void BookBot::readIn(const std::string & filename) {
    ifstream inputFile; 
    string Startkey = "^"; //beginning of sentence
    string value;
    string value2;
    inputFile.open(filename); //open file;

    while(inputFile) {
        inputFile >> value; //read a string into value
        sanitize(value); //clean up string if needed
        size_t end = value.size()-1; 

        if(isEndPunctuation(value[end])) {
            string endKey = "$";
            string endChar(1,value[end]);
            value = value.substr(0,end);
            markov_chain[value].push_back(endChar);
            markov_chain[endChar].push_back(endKey);
            markov_chain[endKey].push_back(Startkey);
            inputFile >> value2;
            sanitize(value2);
            markov_chain[Startkey].push_back(value2);
        } else { 
            //if it DOESN'T HAVE PUNCTUATION
            //Essentially i just want to be able to do         
            //markov_chain[previousString].push_back(newString)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how do i access that previous string?

Well, you have to remember it. Unfortunately your question doesn't make it very clear which strings qualify. I'll assume that it is `value` after processing in this code fragment.

```
string previousString;

while(inputFile) {
    ...
    if(...) {
       ...
       value = value.substr(0,end);
       ...
       markov_chain[Startkey].push_back(value2);
       previousString = value; 
    }
    else {
       markov_chain[previousString].push_back(value);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit**:

From your comment it sounds like the `else` case may also need to set the `previousString`

```
    else {
       markov_chain[previousString].push_back(value);
       previousString = value;
    }
```

in which case it could just be moved to the bottom of the loop.

```
while(inputFile) {
    ...
    previousString = value; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, in this case value would be the previous string. But what if it's a string that's in the middle of the sentence that didn't have a punctuation ending value string before it?

Comment: I don't know your need or your file format. whenever you are at a location where the `previousString` needs to be remembered so that it can be recalled, then you need to save it.